# Is it possible to import another C# project with a main method and set it as the entry point?

Tags: c#, program-entry-point

Is it possible to create a project in C# without a main method, and import another project that has one, and set the entry point to be that main method of the imported project?

The purpose of this is to provide a library complete with its main method and all startup code, requiring only a couple of "plugin" methods. This will minimize boiler-plate (in particular, start-up) code.

Abstract example:

Consider Project 1 with Program.cs:

```
namespace Project1 {
  public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
      Console.WriteLine("All your Main are belong to us");
      Plugin pluginClass = MagicallyGetInstanceOfPluginClassProbablyThroughInjection();
      pluginClass.DoSomethingSpecificDependingOnPluginClassDefinition();
    }

    private Plugin MagicallyGetInstanceOfPluginClassProbablyThroughInjection(){
      /*...*/
    }
  }

  public interface Plugin {
    void DoSomethingSpecificDependingOnPluginClassDefinition();
  }
}
```

Now consider Project 2 with only class MyPlugin.cs:

```
namespace Project2 {
  using Project1;
  public class MyPlugin: Plugin {
    public void DoSomethingSpecificDependingOnPluginClassDefinition() {
      Console.WriteLine("I'm doing something specific!");
    }
  }
}
```

Things to point out:

- Project 1 is just a library, possibly nuget'ed
- It's Project 2 that imports Project 1, not the other way around
- The MyPlugin.cs class above is the only class/file in the project (excluding manifests, app configs, etc)

Aim:

Project 2 should compile into an executable, running Project 1's Main function without writing any more code (no boiler-plate start-up/set-up code). There can then be Project 3, 4, 5, ... that all implement their Plugin-specific code, import Project 1 and run as independent instances.

Is this possible to do? Or do I still have to make a main method in each project that calls the imported project's start-up code? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can... Have you tried setting the startup object?

Comment: so basically a plugin functionality?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a plugin container that scans the directory for assemblies and tries to load them. For this you would need a shared interface (interface known to your program and the plugins.

You could then add the DLLs into a defined plugin directory or you could reference the projects inside your main running project.

An example of the interface could be:

```
public interface IStandAlone
{
    void Run();
}
```

And 1 or to simple implementations could be

```
public class Program1 : IStandAlone
{
    public void Run()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Program1");
    }
}

public class Program2 : IStandAlone
{
    public void Run()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Program 2");
    }
}
```

Then you would need to load the possible assemblies, either from the current assemblies (as is done in this example), or by scanning a directory for dlls that might have your type.

An example that scans the current assemblies for any implementations of the a definite type:

```
public class PluginContainer<T>
{
    Type targetType = typeof(T);

    public virtual IList<Type> GetMatchingTypes()
    {
        Assembly[] currentAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
        IList<Type> items = new List<Type>();
        if (currentAssemblies == null || currentAssemblies.Length == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No assemblies found!");
            return items;
        }
        foreach (Assembly ass in currentAssemblies)
        {
            try
            {
                var types = ass.GetTypes();
                foreach (var t in types)
                {
                    if (t.IsInterface)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (!(targetType.IsAssignableFrom(t)))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    items.Add(t);
                }
            }
            catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException rtle)
            {
                /* In case the loading failed, scan the types that it was able to load */
                Console.WriteLine(rtle.Message);
                if (rtle.Types != null)
                {
                    foreach (var t in rtle.Types)
                    {
                        if (t.IsInterface)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        if (!(targetType.IsAssignableFrom(t)))
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        items.Add(t);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                /* General exception */
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        return items;
    }

    public IList<T> GetPlugins()
    {
        IList<Type> matchingTypes = GetMatchingTypes();
        IList<T> items = new List<T>();
        if (matchingTypes == null || matchingTypes.Count == 0) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No matching types of {0} found", typeof(T).FullName);
            return null;
        }
        foreach (Type type in matchingTypes)
        {
            try
            {
                T nObj = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                items.Add(nObj);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error occured trying to run {0}\r\n{1}", type.FullName, ex.Message);
            }
        }
        return items;
    }
}
```

which can then be used inside a main method to scan for any available plugins, and to execute them:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    PluginContainer<IStandAlone> container = new PluginContainer<IStandAlone>();
    var plugins = container.GetPlugins();
    foreach (var plugin in plugins)
    {
        plugin.Run();
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

which eventually gives as an output:

```
Program1
Program 2
```

Please keep in mind, that this is a very basic example, and that a well thought out interface should be in place, that really only contains the basics, and might give some feedback to the program running the plugins (though this shouldn't be a requirement). Also offering a versions for plugins, maybe an update Url, and such things could be handy in case your plugins can be maintained or implemented by 3th party providers...

Answer (score 0):

I believe the requirement for a start-up method is that it's signature needs to be `public static void` and it needs to have a single `string[]` parameter. It may also need to be named "Main", but I doubt it. If a method matches those requirements it should be available to pick as the start-up method in a project's properties.

However the start-up method is what's used to run a stand-alone executable program when it's launched. I believe what you are looking for is more of a plug-in architecture. You can create an attribute and tag your entry point method(s) with that attribute. Then, in your service, you would need to reflect over the classes in the plug-in assembly which you are loading and find methods marked with your custom attribute, and invoke the appropriate one.

Sorry if this sounds a bit vague but a "plugin architecture" is not a trivial topic.

An alternative would be to use the `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(string)` method to just launch your "plug-in" as a stand-alone program.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you're asking for. Every C# project is either a `.exe` or a `.dll`. A `.dll` does not have a main method, but an `.exe` needs one. [Here's the link describing what it should look like](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3.aspx).

If you have many very similar applications then you can move all the common stuff in a `.dll` project and reference it in all the applications. Then you can call the methods from each `.exe`. You'll still have a `Main()` method in each `.exe`, but it will only contain one line which calls the common implementation.

Or you can do something like a plugin architecture, where you have one `.exe` and all the other applications are `.dll` projects, which are loaded and executed by the `.exe` as needed.

Six of one, half a dozen of the other, it's all the same in the end.